# How to lazily initialize a template tuple of unique_ptrs?

Tags: c++, templates, asynchronous, c++14

I need to write a class that creates snapshots of data based on asyncronous callbacks. For example, if I have an integer stream and a double stream, I have to push the data into a queue and process the data once there's a value for both of them. My class looks like this atm:

```c
template<typename... Types>
class Dataholder{
private:
 std::deque<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Types>...>> data_frame_deque_;
public:
  template <class T>
  void push(T data); //find the next tuple that doesn't yet have value for type T and add it, or create new tuple
  void run_if_frame_ready(std::function<void (std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Types>...>)&> fun); //run function fun, that accepts a tuple as defined in data_frame_queue_;
}
```

And example usage should look like this:

```c
Dataholder<int, double> holder;
void myProcessingFunction(std::tuple<int,double>& data)
{
 //do stuff
}
int main(void)
{
  holder.push(42);
  holder.push(3.14);
  holder.run_if_frame_ready(myProcessingFunction);
}
```

The `Dataholder::push()` function checks each tuple in the deqeue, if a frame exists, and if so, if the corresponding value is initialized. If not, initialize it, if it is, move to the next dataframe/create a new empty frame and put the data there.

The `Dataholder::run_if_frame_ready()` function checks if the first frame in the queue is fully initialized. If it is it pops it off and passes it to the given function.

My question is, how do I correctly initialize all members using C++ templates? How do I implement the push function? I understand I can make checks with something like `std::is_same`, but I don't quite understand how. For the time being, it is okay if all types are only used once, but is this possible to implement with multiple entries of the same type? E.g. that then the push function can be `push(T data, int index)` for the case where the class is used like `Dataholder<int, int>`?

Comment: There is too much going on here. You have threads, mutexes, callbacks, templates and lazy initializing uncopyable things. If you're asking about templates and lazy initializing, remove everything thread related.

Comment: on it. I figured I'd provide some context to avoid "why do you even need this" comments.

Comment: It might be easier to have a tuple of queues, one for each data type. Then you can check each queue and if all of them are non-empty (that's O(1) for a queue), you can take out the oldest from each and process them together. This would allow using std::queue, because you'd only access the front and back, and not have to iterate through all elements.

If you have a queue of tuples, you'll have to go through the queue in O(n) time to check for frames.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet that is also an option but it still leaves open my question of how to do the required template magic for it. The current run-function I am working on uses std::move to avoid recreated the data, since in my usecase the frames are a few MB each and I want to avoid unnecessary de-/constuctor calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am immensely surprised by the difficulty involved in doing something so simple. This is the implementation where you have a tuple of deques, which ends up being exactly as efficient as you could do by hand, ie you don't loop through the queue looking for an empty entry.

```
template<typename>
void get();  // for ADL

template<typename... Types>
class Dataholder{
    using Deques = std::tuple<std::deque<std::unique_ptr<Types>>...>;

    Deques deq;

    template<typename F, size_t... Is>
    void run(F&& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        std::forward<F>(f)(*(get<Is>(deq).front())...);
    }

    template<size_t... Is>
    bool empty(std::index_sequence<Is...>) const
    {
        // mock fold expression
        bool e = false;
        char unused[] = {(e |= get<Is>(deq).empty())...};
        (void)unused;
        return e;
    }

    template<size_t... Is>
    void pop(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        char unused[] = {(get<Is>(deq).pop_front(), 0)...};
        (void)unused;
    }

public:
    // push by index
    template<size_t I, typename T>
    void push(T&& data)
    {
        using Tuple = std::tuple<Types...>;
        using type = std::tuple_element_t<I, Tuple>;
        get<I>(deq).emplace_back(new type(std::forward<T>(data)));
    }

    // push by type
    template<typename T>
    void push(T&& data)
    {
        using type = std::deque<std::unique_ptr<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>;
        get<type>(deq).emplace_back(new auto(std::forward<T>(data)));
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return empty(std::index_sequence_for<Types...>{});
    }

    void pop()
    {
        pop(std::index_sequence_for<Types...>{});
    }

    // you don't want std::function for this
    template<typename F>
    void run_if_frame_ready(F&& f)
    {
        if(empty())
            return;
        run(std::forward<F>(f), std::index_sequence_for<Types...>{});
    }
};
```

And run as

```
void f(int i, double d)
{
    std::cout << i << ' ' << d;
}

int main()
{
    Dataholder<int, double> holder;
    holder.push(42);
    holder.run_if_frame_ready(f);  // does nothing
    holder.push(3.14);
    holder.run_if_frame_ready(f);
}
```

Comment: Calling `holder.pop()` gives me an error on my machine. Looks awesome otherwise. I'll try to see if I can adapt it for my usecase.

Comment: Ok I cannot figure out how the argument expansion works. I need the run(and push) functions to lock the `deq` member and if empty is false(there is a full data frame), extract the first frame(FIFO style) while locked, release the lock and pass the frame to the provided function.

Comment: run should work something like this: `/*acquire lock*/std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Types>...> tup = *(get<Is>(deq).front());pop();/*release lock*/std::forward<F>(f)(tup);`

Comment: @jaaq pop is fixed. Your locking should be independent from this.

Comment: Thanks! Why should locking be independent? Doesn't this introduce room for error? If I know that this class will be used in a concurrent setting, why not take care of the critical parts(push,pop, empty) right away?

Comment: Also, if I need to concurrently request the front finished dataframe and return 1 unique frame each to the run function, I need to run getting and popping the data while locked, but the functor outside, since the parameters it gets are now no longer in the datastructure.

Comment: also, [your solution](https://pastebin.com/zyWt0j3m) copies around the values a lot. I will be using this for big matrices, hence I want the values to be moved around. Sadly I cannot even figure out how to store the sequence pack from the run function inside a variable without unpacking, so I can do the locked pop of a frame before running the function outside the lock myself. I like your implementation because the resulting functor parameters are cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Your DataHolder can be implemented like that:

```
template<typename... Types>
class Dataholder {
public:
  // alias for entry_type
  using entry_type = std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Types>...>;

  template <class T>
  void push(T&& data); // implemented in the .h file, but outside the class

  size_t size() const {
    return data_frame_deque_.size();
  }

  bool frame_ready() const {
    // C++17 fold expression
    // (link for a C++14 version without fold expression provided below)
    return (std::get<std::unique_ptr<Types>>(data_frame_deque_.front()) && ...);
  }

  void run_if_frame_ready(std::function<void(entry_type&&)>&& fun) {
    if(frame_ready()) {
      fun(std::move(data_frame_deque_.front()));
      data_frame_deque_.pop_front();
    }
  }

private:
  std::deque<entry_type> data_frame_deque_;
};
```

With the push function:

```
template<typename... Types>
template <class T>
void Dataholder<Types...>::push(T&& data) {

  // find the next tuple that doesn't yet have value for type T
  std::unique_ptr<T>* placeholder = nullptr;
  for(auto& tup : data_frame_deque_) {
    auto& uptr = std::get<std::unique_ptr<T>>(tup);
      if (!uptr) {
        placeholder = &uptr;
        break;
      }
  }

  // if all tuples already have this type, create a new one
  if (placeholder == nullptr) {
    data_frame_deque_.push_back(entry_type());
    placeholder = &std::get<std::unique_ptr<T>>(data_frame_deque_.back());
  }

  // add the item into the tuple
  *placeholder = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<T>(data));
}
```

[Code above (C++17)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c60ddec73157e058)

[Code for C++14, without fold expression](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd39e52d7c7ba942)

Note that if the code can be used from different threads proper locking shall be added to protect the access to the deque.

Comment: I am sadly forced to use c++14. Do you know a workaround for the fold?

Comment: added, enjoy :-)

Comment: Tested it and found out that the last line calling `make_unique` uses the copy constructor. Do you know of a way to implement push without making a copy? As stated in a comment above, my data frames are quite large and this will be used quite often.

Comment: @jaaq **no copies!** only *moving around*. You can [for example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c14a088430bf5c84) use Dataholder that holds a type that is not copyable, e.g. `unique_ptr`. Which proves no copy is occurring. Of course if you use a type that doesn't support efficient move or doesn't support move at all, you will see copies. But it's not from my Dataholder. To avoid redundant copies, make sure to call `Dataholder::push(T&&)` with `rvalue`, e.g.: `dataholder.push(std::move(data));`

Comment: Awesome, gonna check it out monday :) accepted your answer it has been extremely helpful and is adaptable enough for me to retrofit locking the critical methods. Just once last question: Do you know how to expand the tuple and move it's parts into the arguments of the functor with c++14? e.g. `dataholder<int,double>::run(f)` with f as as `f(int&& a, double&& b)`? Similar to PasserBy's answer, but I simply couldn't adapt their solution to include locking; which was easy with your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with Passer Bys version as their solution allowed for using the class with multiple instances of the same type which might come up. Also figured out how to pop the frame into a variable and use it later so that locking can be introduced. Also moved some public interface to private since they're not needed for my usecase. If you use this for something else and need to access some private functions, make sure that everything is locked correctly. Here's the final product:

```
#include <deque>
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <mutex>

template<typename>
void get();  // for ADL

template<typename... Types>
class Dataholder{
private:
    using Deques = std::tuple<std::deque<std::unique_ptr<Types>>...>;

    Deques deq;
    std::mutex mutex_;

    template<typename F, size_t... Is>
    void run(F&& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {   
        mutex_.lock();
        if(!empty())
        {
            auto t = std::make_tuple(*(get<Is>(deq).front())...);
            pop();
            mutex_.unlock(); //unlock mutex before processing the removed data
            std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<Is>(std::move(t))...);
        }
        else
        {
            mutex_.unlock();
        }
    }

    template<size_t... Is>
    bool empty(std::index_sequence<Is...>) const
    {
        //make sure this is locked by convention!
        // mock fold expression
        bool e = false;
        char unused[] = {(e |= get<Is>(deq).empty())...};
        (void)unused;
        return e;
    }

    template<size_t... Is>
    void pop(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        //disable type narrowing warning for unused variable
        #pragma GCC diagnostic push
        #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wnarrowing"
        //we need this for being able to resolve the pop_front call
        char unused[] = {(get<Is>(deq).pop_front(), 0)...};
        (void)unused;
        #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return empty(std::index_sequence_for<Types...>{});
    }

    void pop()
    {
        pop(std::index_sequence_for<Types...>{});
    }

public:
    // push by index
    template<size_t I, typename T>
    void push(T&& data)
    {
        using Tuple = std::tuple<Types...>;
        using type = std::tuple_element_t<I, Tuple>;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex_);
        get<I>(deq).emplace_back(new type(std::forward<T>(data)));
    }

    // push by type
    template<typename T>
    void push(T&& data)
    {
        using type = std::deque<std::unique_ptr<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex_);
        get<type>(deq).emplace_back(new auto(std::forward<T>(data)));
    }

    template<typename F>
    void run_if_frame_ready(F&& f)
    {
        //locked in private callee
        run(std::forward<F>(f), std::index_sequence_for<Types...>{});
    }
};
```